# Dative after 'von' with compound personal names

Tags: dative, person-names

The preposition *von* takes the dative in German, but I'm unsure how to form the dative of a "compound" personal name like *Karl der Große*.  As a proper noun, *Karl* does not change, but does *der Große* become *dem Großen*?  For example, should I write *die Vorfahren von Karl dem Großen* or *die Vorfahren von Karl der Große*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Correct is

> die Vorfahren von Karl **dem** Großen

Here is a link, using dative case:
[Grab von **Karl dem Großen** bleibt verschollen](http://www.spiegel.de/wissenschaft/mensch/aachener-dom-grab-von-karl-dem-grossen-bleibt-verschollen-a-695574.html)

An example for genitive case:
[Die Kaiserkrönung **Karls des Großen**](http://www.dw.com/de/die-kaiserkr%C3%B6nung-karls-des-gro%C3%9Fen-25-dezember-800/a-3840342)

Another one for accusative case:
[Wann, wo und warum krönte Papst Leo III. **Karl den Großen** zum Kaiser?](http://www.navigator-allgemeinwissen.de/die-wichtigsten-fragen-und-antworten-zur-weltgeschichte/fruehes-mittelalter/karolinger/karl-der-grosse-koenig-a-kaiser/1204-wann-wo-und-warum-kroente-papst-leo-iii-karl-den-grossen-zum-kaiser.html)

Although *»Karl der Große«* is a proper name, the part *»der Große«* still is an [apposition](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apposition) (Latin: ad = "near" and positio = "placement"), and has to be inflected according to its grammatical environment.

The subclass of appositions used in names of rulers is called »weite Apposition« (*wide apposition*). You also find it in *»Heinrich VIII«* which is spoken *»Heinrich der Achte«*. This is just the same as in »*Bob der Baumeister«* (*Bob the builder*) or *»Nino der Frisör«* or even in *»Barbara, meine Schwester«*.

The other form is called »enge Apposition« (*narrow apposition*), for which *»Herr«* in *»Herr Müller«* is an example. In *»Frau Maier, die Ärztin«,* you have both: a narrow (*Frau*) and a wide apposition (*die Ärztin*).

Wide appositions often are subclauses (marked bold in this examples):

> Walter, **der Bruder von Martin,** kauft ein Buch.
>   Walter, **Martin's brother,** buys a book.

If you use those names together with this appositions, you also have to inflect them:

> Die Erwähnung Walters, **des** Bruders von Martin, brachte Barbara zum erröten.
>   Dieses Buch gehört Walter, **dem** Bruder von Martin.
>   Jetzt sehe ich auch Walter, **den** Bruder von Martin.

But also narrow appositions need to be inflected:

> (Nom) **Herr** Fink trinkt Wasser.
>   (Gen) Das Geschäft des **Herren** Gruber liegt in der Neugasse.
>   (Dat) Dieses Buch gehört **Herren** Schneider.
>   (Akk) Hast du **Herren** Lechner gesehen?

Comment: Thank you.  That's a wonderfully detailed explanation that has helped me a lot.

Comment: Warum "Herren" und nicht "Herrn"? Hat das stilistische Ursachen?

Comment: @Beta: Das ist Geschmacksache. Beides ist erlaubt. Siehe https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Herr

Answer (score 1):

"Die Vorfahren von Karl **dem Großen**" is correct. You're right, the name doesn't change but the byname is adapted to the sentence as it's virtually a description. (Please note that this case is genitive here.)


Examples:

> "Look at this statue of Charlemagne.": "Sehen Sie sich diese Statue **von Karl dem Großen** an." or also possible: "Sehen Sie sich diese Statue **Karls des Großen** an."
>
> "Artists were welcome at the royal court of Augustus II the Strong.": "Am Hofe von **August dem Starken** waren Künstler willkommen." or also possible: "Am Hofe **Augusts des Starken** waren Künstler willkommen." (Original german name "August der Starke".)
>
> "Practically I don't know much about Agrippina the Younger.": "Von **Agrippina der Jüngeren** weiss ich so gut wie gar nichts." (Original german name "Agrippina die Jüngere".)

Comment: What is genitive there?